# Why is the following equality true?

Tags: summation

I am trying to understand a proof - why does this hold?

$$\sum\limits_{i}\left(\sum\limits_{0 \le j \le i}f(a_{i-j})f(b_{j})\right)x^i=\left(\sum\limits_{i}f(a_i)x^i\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i}f(b_i)x^i\right)$$

Comment: What is $i$ summing over? If it is summing over all natural numbers, then the statement is not true in general.

Comment: True if $i,j\in\{0,1,\dots\}$. To convince yourself: find the coefficient of $x^n$ on RHS and compare it with the one on LHS.